# How to get Subscription list of Google Reader

Tags: android, google-reader

I can get authentication key and token from google reader but I don't know how to get an input stream from http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/subscription/list with that token to get subscription list. I'm

Any helps?
Thanks in advance.